# How do you explain the unit of this formula?

Tags: physics, network, unit-of-measure

I have trouble trying to interpret the following formula:

$$G_{SCI} = \mu N^{span} G^3 \mathrm{arcsinh}\,(\rho \Delta f^2)$$

$$G_{SCI} = \frac{P_{SCI}}{B},$$ where $P_{SCI}$ is the self-channel interference noise ($W$), $B$ is the bandwidth (Hz), so the unit of $G_{SCI}$ is $W \cdot Hz^{-1}$

$$\mu = \frac{3 \gamma^2}{2\pi \alpha |\beta_2|},\qquad \rho = \frac{\pi^2 |\beta_2|}{2 \alpha}$$

where $\gamma = 1.3 W^{-1} \cdot km^{-1}$, $\beta_2 = -21.3\ ps^2 \cdot km^{-1}$, $\alpha = 0.22 \ dB \cdot km^{-1}$, $N^{span}$ is the number of spans, which is linear, $G$ is the power spectral density ($W/Hz$).

The unit of $\mu$ will be $W^{-2} \cdot Hz^2 \cdot dB^{-1}$, the unit of $\rho$ will be $Hz^{-2} \cdot dB^{-1}$, the overall unit will be :

$$W^{-2} \cdot Hz^2 \cdot dB^{-1} \cdot W^3 \cdot Hz^{-3} \mathrm{arcsinh}\,(dB^{-1}) = W \cdot Hz^{-1} \cdot dB^{-1} \mathrm{arcsinh}\,(dB^{-1})$$

So it seems to me that the $\mathrm{arcsinh}\,(dB^{-1})$ will produce a measure with unit in $dB$, which I don't understand why. Could anybody please explain that to me ?

Comment: This may be better suited for [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks @Brian I'll post in the physic forum too

Answer (score 1):

Decibel ($dB$) is a unitless quantity (same as angle). Therefore applying any mathematical function is allowed, and will not change the dimensionality. Maybe the easier thing to say that the units of $dB$ is $\log_{10}\frac WW$.

Comment: If it is as you said, then the LHS of the first formula, the unit is $W \cdot Hz^{-1}$, the RHS is $W \cdot Hz^{-1} \cdot dB^{-1} \cdot dB^{-1}$, which is very strange

Comment: Think of decibel as a numeric constant, such as $\pi$ or $e$. You can just ignore those when you talk about dimensions. But, to convince yourself, calculate what is the dimensionality of $1dB$ in terms of meters, seconds, and kilograms, starting from the definition.